# How to format a string in a particular way in Sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, split

I have a SQL (SQL Server 2016) column which represents a version. It is NVARCHAR. I want to display the column in a consistent format. I did some research on FORMAT but couldn't find a solution. Any pointers please?

The output should always be of the form: XX.XX.XXXX

You can assume that there are two digits before the first decimal point (I was able to use CASE for fixing that)

```
Sample Input
============
13.0.1221.00
11.00.1111

Desired Output
==============
13.00.1221
11.00.1111
```

Comment: Can you post your query? What's wrong with it?

Comment: You are trimming, stuffing, and likely going to need to something else too. This should be handled on the application side IMHO.

Comment: Can you show some more possible values in your column ?

Comment: This has the tell tale signs of improper normalization to me. I have a feeling this is 4 value shoved into a single column. Things like software versions get this type of denormalized structure all too frequently. Instead of separate columns for Major, Minor, Release, Revision they get crammed into a single column and then it becomes painful to extract it.

Answer (score 3):

```
Declare @YourTable table (SomeField varchar(25))
Insert Into @YourTable values
('13.0.1221.00'),
('11.00.1111')

Select A.*
      ,Format(Pos1,'00')+'.'+Format(Pos2,'00')+'.'+Format(Pos3,'0000')
 From @YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
    Select Pos1 = xDim.value('/x[1]','int')
          ,Pos2 = xDim.value('/x[2]','int')
          ,Pos3 = xDim.value('/x[3]','int')
     From (Select Cast('<x>' + Replace(A.SomeField,'.','</x><x>')+'</x>' as XML) as xDim) A
       ) B
```

Returns

```
SomeField       (No column name)
13.0.1221.00    13.00.1221
11.00.1111      11.00.1111
```

Comment: Thanks! The two sample values that I posted represent the "problem" values that I was facing :(

Agree with the normalization comment --- unfortunately, this is a legacy issue that I have to deal with and cannot split up the values into separate columns (at this time)

Comment: @syzygy78 Happy to help

Comment: @syzygy78 For the record, I've inherited far worse.  :)

Answer (score 0):

> The output should always be of the form: XX.XX.XXXX

Forcing three digits into two would end up bad I guess, but if those are the requirements:

```
Declare @YourTable table (s varchar(25))
Insert Into @YourTable values
('13.0.1221.00'),
('11.00.1111'),
('189.256.0000001'),
('7'),
('.19.'),
('13.4.'),
('..11'),
('A..B'),
(null),
('......')

;WITH rs AS (SELECT s, REVERSE('0' + s) AS rs FROM @YourTable)
    SELECT REVERSE(LEFT(ISNULL(PARSENAME(rs, 3), '') + '0000', 4) + '.' +
                   LEFT(ISNULL(PARSENAME(rs, 2), '') + '00'  , 2) + '.' +
                   LEFT(ISNULL(PARSENAME(rs, 1), '') + '00'  , 2)), s
    FROM rs
```

**Result:**

```
13.00.1221  13.0.1221.00
11.00.1111  11.00.1111
89.56.0001  189.256.0000001
07.00.0000  7
00.19.0000  .19.
13.04.0000  13.4.
00.00.0011  ..11
0A.00.000B  A..B
00.00.0000  NULL
00.00.0000  ......
```